# How to call C program when start procedure in android?

Tags: android

I want to execute a C program automatically during the start-up process. My C program named smackload.

I try to add `service smackload /data/local/smackload` in `init.rc`. It is no use.

I also add a command in one Action:   `exec /data/local/smackload`

Could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use NDK for that.For more details see this :-http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html